# Jquery Validation not compatible with Browser IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, jquery-validate

The following code works in all browsers except IE. I need to fix it.

```
$(function () {

    // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
    $("form[name=firstform]").validate({
        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true,
                alpha: true
            },
        },
        messages: {
            username: {
                required: "Please Provide Your Name",
                alpha: "Name Should contains only alphabets",
            },
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Could somebody who has worked with IE for this type of jquery validation kindly help me to fix this problem?

Comment: Hi, Which IE version are you using ?

Comment: for sample i put here for one field after user name rules i can add any number of fields  separating by commas, now im using IE8

Comment: $(function () {

    // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
    $("form[name=firstform]").validate({
        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true,
               
            } ,mobile:{number:true,  }
        },
        messages: {
            username: {
                required: "Please Provide Your Name",
                } ,mobile:{number:"Mobile should conations only numbers", }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});

Comment: **This plugin absolutely works fine with IE8**.  By chance are you using a different version of Explorer in "IE 8 Mode"?  If so, you need to know that this is not a proper emulation of the real browser.  [MS provides VPC and free hard drive images containing IE 8 just for this kind of testing](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads).

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the trailing commas in your code:

```
$(function () {

    // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
    $("form[name=firstform]").validate({
        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true,
                alpha: true
            } // Here
        },
        messages: {
            username: {
                required: "Please Provide Your Name",
                alpha: "Name Should contains only alphabets" // Here
            } // Here
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this also not working sir, i tried more times in IE 8 but no result

Comment: What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: jquery-1.9.1.js,jquery.validate.js i using these jquerys using sir

Comment: I'll bet the OP is using "IE 8 Mode" in place of the real IE8.  "IE 8 Mode" was never meant to be a simulation, emulation, or a testing environment... it's only a fallback for older websites that don't work properly in newer versions of IE.